# Create output file for each of input file from directory of files in Spring Batch

Tags: java, file, spring-batch, export-to-csv, one-to-one

I have a directory of CSV files which contains transaction information. 
I need to read each file , process some business logic (validate with DB to check valid account and transaction or not) and write the valid transactions into new output file.

**Input:**
Tranx_100.csv, Tranx_101.csv, Tranx_102.csv....

**Ouput:**
Tranx_100_output.csv, Tranx_101_output.csv, Tranx_102_output.csv....

Want to use spring batch for this. Any suggestions on how to implement this?

For each file as input, process, output are same - can i run them as part of '**Step**' and repeat the **step** for each input file in a **JOB**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping on the same step or using multiple steps in a single job, I would use a job instance for each file (ie the file is an identifying job parameter) and launch jobs in parallel. This approach has multiple advantages:

- Fault-tolerance: In case of failure, only the failed file is re-processed
- Scalability: You can run multiple jobs in parallel easily
- Logging: logs will be separated by design
- And all the good reasons of making one thing do one thing and do it well

Comment: Dear Mahmoud, Thanks for the suggestion. Can you share any reference code for generating Job at run time and Running them in parallel.